# Slide accordion to browser top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, accordion

I have a accordion menu with very lengthy content. So I need to implement slide effect when accordion content is opened up.

Currently if you open up the first two menu items then the last item shows up the content below the viewport so I need to have the slide up effect for the accordion menu items.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Accordion
    $(".menu_body").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class menu_body
    $(".menu_head").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".menu_body").slideToggle(400); 
        var plusmin;
        plusmin = $(this).children(".plusminus").text();

        $(this).children("span.down-arrow").toggleClass("up-arrow");        
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/orAKEVu/12)**

Comment: If possible provide us jsfiddle link

Comment: @PandiyanCool oops ... Forgot to link. Added now

Answer (score 0):

Check out this, Is this expected?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Accordion
    $(".menu_body").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class menu_body
    $(".menu_head").click(function(){

      $(".menu_body").each(function (event){
        $(".menu_body").hide();
      });
        $(this).next(".menu_body").slideToggle(400); 
        var plusmin;
        plusmin = $(this).children(".plusminus").text();

        $(this).children("span.down-arrow").toggleClass("up-arrow");        
    });

    });
```

Comment: I have edited the question. It is not scroll, I need slide effect

Comment: I need multiple menu to be opened up so can not restrict for one at a time

Comment: @Sowmya So you want to keep the currently opened menu at top